# In JAVA API why equality check using '==' rather than String.equals() method

Tags: java, string

I was going through API code i found this in JAVA Api

```
java.io.FilePermission.getMask(String actions) {
    int mask = NONE;

    // Null action valid?
    if (actions == null) {
        return mask;
    }
    // Check against use of constants (used heavily within the JDK)
    if (actions == SecurityConstants.FILE_READ_ACTION) {
        return READ;
    } else if (actions == SecurityConstants.FILE_WRITE_ACTION) {
        return WRITE;
    } else if (actions == SecurityConstants.FILE_EXECUTE_ACTION) {
        return EXECUTE;
    } else if (actions == SecurityConstants.FILE_DELETE_ACTION) {
        return DELETE;
    } else if (actions == SecurityConstants.FILE_READLINK_ACTION) {
        return READLINK;
    }
....
....
.....
}
```

can any one tell me why they have used '==' operator instead of .equlas() method. :?

Comment: Type int is a primitive type, so == is enough

Comment: What is `SecurityConstants`? An enum? (edit: doesn't look like it; indeed, this code will certainly fail)

Comment: should be asked from author

Comment: Those constants are strings, and nothing will fail if those constants are used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @fge This code will not certainly fail. Actually, it will generally succeed (in fact, it is [private in `FilePermissions`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/FilePermission.java#FilePermission.getMask%28java.lang.String%29) and thus the internal implementation has full control over the values passed to that function, so it will *certainly* succeed).

Comment: @JasonC OK, I see. That's risky code, though.

Comment: @fge I agree. It's a special case, I guess. If you trace back through the code it's *all* private and package private stuff. I am surprised, though, that they don't clearly document that behavior in the method docs, even if it is internal. There's not even a note in a comment. Not sure why they didn't just use an `enum`, or even just dummy `Object` instances to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of *String interning*. What happens is that the compiler interns **String literals** in memory at compile time (this is done to save memory). When you compare string literals with `==`, it will work because they are in the same memory location.

I would recommend you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java), so you get the idea. Here is the example (from that answer) and its explanation (mine):

```
1  // These two have the same value
2  new String("test").equals("test") --> true
3   
4  // ... but they are not the same object
5  new String("test") == "test" --> false
6   
7  // ... neither are these
8  new String("test") == new String("test") --> false
9  
10 // ... but these are because literals are interned by 
11 // the compiler and thus refer to the same object
12 "test" == "test" --> true
13 
14 // concatenation of string literals happens at compile time,
15 // also resulting in the same object
16 "test" == "te" + "st" --> true
17 
18 // but .substring() is invoked at runtime, generating distinct objects
19 "test" == "!test".substring(1) --> false
```

**Explanation:**

> Why does line 12 and 16 evaluate to true? Because of `String` **interning**. What happens in these cases is that the compiler interns `String` literals in memory at compile time (this is done to save memory). In line 12 and 16 the `String`literals that are beign compared are in the **same memory location**, so the comparison with `==` operator returns `true`.
>   However, this is not recommended unless you want better performance (comparing memory addresses is a lot “cheaper” than a loop) and you are sure that the `String`s being compared are interned literals.

**Remember** that [those `SecurityConstants` are strings.](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/security/util/SecurityConstants.html)

Comment: Did you verbatim copy [somebody else's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/616460) from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java to your blog, then claim it as yours *and* spam a link to your blog here instead of linking to the appropriate SO question?

Comment: @JasonC you are right, I forgot I to mention the *initial source*. Edited. But in fact, I didn't claim it as mine; I put a link to the answer in the blog. Also, I took the example, but the explanation is from my words.

Answer (score 2):

That `action` should be one of those constants declared in `SecurityConstants` class, which already instantiated and passed to that method. So it doesn't matter whether we compare with `equals()` or `==`.

Comment: I think they are sure that always the same instance will be passed, but in there API anyone can assigne new instance from java.io.FilePermission.FilePermission(String path, String actions); and that is public construtor, but for the performance perspective this is good.

Comment: @Khushnood, `private static int getMask(String actions)` is a private method, so, It can't be used anybody other than the user.

Comment: but any one can use from the  java.io.FilePermission.FilePermission(String path, String actions); constructor that is public....

Answer (score 0):

This works as long as `actions` is *100% guaranteed* to reference one of those constant instances. Note that Java pools string literals so it also works when comparing to the *literal* "something".

```
class Example {

    static final String VALUE1 = "something";
    static final String VALUE2 = "another";

    void example () {
        String v;
        v = VALUE1; assert(v == VALUE1);
        v = VALUE2; assert(v == VALUE2);
        v = "something"; assert(v == VALUE1);
        v = new String("something"); assert(v != VALUE1); // <- not equal!
    }

}
```

Comment: Those constants are `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

In the JVM  string constant pool essentially cache all string literals.Therefore the same object will remain in the memorry. SO  JVM  avoid creating a new string object each time a literal is declared, which could get very expensive very quickly. Because of this still we can use ==.

Normally ==  is used to compare two object references. for the string comparison better to sue the equals() method. but when it deals with constant String you can still use == . but it should be done only if you sure it uses for constants.